# How to repeat every X seconds in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, infinite-loop

I am trying to build a simple single view app which runs an infinite slide show of a selection of images with a time delay between each image change.

The code I wrote for this is below. I tried to put this into viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear but the screen remained blank which I guess is because the function never finishes due to the infinite loop.

I learnt a bit of Python before iOS and with tkinter, your code would go into the mainloop. But I am not quite sure how to do the equivalent in Swift

Could someone please explain why I am having this problem and how to do this in Swift. Thanks.

```
var arrayimages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "charizard")!,UIImage(named:"Flying_Iron_Man")!]

var x: Int = 0
var images: UIImage
let arraycount = arrayimages.count

repeat{
    images = arrayimages[(x % arraycount)]
    sleep(1)
    slideshow.image = images
    x++
} while true
```

NB: slideshow is an image view outlet.

Comment: Does while(true) not work?

Comment: The reason this wouldn't work is because the code is executing in the main thread, which is the thread where the UI works, if you block the main thread the UI can't update. By executing an infinite loop, you are blocking the main thread indefinitely, so the UI will never update and your images won't change. The answers suggesting you use NSTimer are good answers, but I thought I'd explain why it's not working the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for NSTimer

```
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
    1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("doYourTask"),
    userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

The first argument is how frequently you want the timer to fire, the second is what object is going to have the selector that gets called, the third is the selector name, the fourth is any extra information you want to pass as a parameter on the timer object, and the fifth is whether this should repeat.

If you want to stop the code at any future point:

```
timer.invalidate()
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a repeating NSTimer:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0,
  target: self,
  selector: "animateFunction:",
  userInfo: nil,
  repeats: true)
```

Then write a function animateFunction:

```
func animateFunction(timer: NSTimer)
{
  //Display the next image in your array, or loop back to the beginning
}
```

### Edit: Updated for modern Swift versions: (>= Swift 5)

This has changed a lot since I posted this answer. NSTimer is now called Timer in Swift, and the syntax of the `scheduledTimer()` method has changed. The method signature is now `scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)`

Also, the way you create a selector has changed

So the call would be

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0,
  target: self,
  selector: #selector(animateFunction(_:)),
  userInfo: nil,
  repeats: true)
```

And the animateFunction might look like this:

```
func animateFunction(timer: Timer)
{
  //Display the next image in your array, or loop back to the beginning
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me understand better what I needed to do but didn't quite work for me. I had to use '.' instead of '(' between `NSTImer` and `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` as suggested by **tbondwilkinson**. Could it be because I am using a different swift version from you? (2.1)

Comment: No, it's because I am working mostly in Objective-C these days and am getting a little rusty with Swift syntax. I edited my answer. Is that the correct syntax now?